# System trashed after recommended Ubuntu updates- what do I do?

Tags: boot, updates, system

everything running fine when Ubuntu messaged me it had a large number of updates to install.   I gave it root access and ran the updates, then rebooted.
Now the system will no longer boot!

When I start the system I get a message:

> > >
> >     ! The system is running in low-graphics mode

Your screen, graphics card, and input device settings
could not be detected correctly.  You will need to configure these yourself.

> > >

The mouse works and I click OK, then I get a menu with 4 options:

- Run in low-graphics mode for just one session - this sticks at 'Stopping System V runlevel compatibility, blinking cursor goes nowhere.  'could not write bytes: Broken pipe"
- Reconfigure graphics  - all options off this menu go nowhere
- Troubleshoot the error - this just brings up log files
- Exit to console login - this also stops at 'could not write bytes: Broken pipe', etc. goes nowhere.

I am not really savvy with Ubuntu, just use it for my OS.  Has anyone had this happen?  Is there any way to remove these updates??  I had no problems with the system before they loaded today   :(

Thanks- jeffpas

Ubuntu with Linux 3.5.0-43-generic

---

dobey- I click "Add Comment" and nothing happens, I can't seem to reply to your question.

I have not done anything with the NVIDIA drivers, I'm using what came with the Ubuntu install for this version.  Why would they become an issue now?  Is there some way to fix this?
I've tried booting in recovery mode, and it sticks at 'Stopping save kernel messages' and a cursor, and goes nowhere.
thanks

---

Avinash- thanks I'll remember that- but I found out the problem.
My root filesystem / was at 100% full.
I got out to a prompt and deleted some files, and the system booted and I can get in now everything appears OK.
Strange, that it didn't just say that, the message was pretty misleading.  WHEW!

Comment: Are you using the proprietary nvidia drivers on your system?

Comment: @jeffpas you can answer your own question and mark it as accepted answer to close this out.

Answer (score 1):

- Open the virtual console by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> while the screen says `Running in low graphics mode`.
- Login with your username and password.Then run the below commands,

  ```
  sudo rm /etc/X11/xorg.conf
  sudo shutdown -r now
  ```

OR

```
  sudo apt-get update
  sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
  sudo apt-get install --reinstall unity
```

- After rebooted,you will get back to your original screen.